SweetAlert delete confirmation of table row only deletes the last row
I have an HTML table with rows containing data from my SQL database, with the table body being under a for loop to display the fetchall rows. Before deleting the specific row, I want a SweetAlert to pop up for confirmation. However, it only deletes the last row instead of the row I want?
Here is my HTML table:
<div class="table-responsive my-5">
    <table id="table-address-book" class="display table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align: center;">
                <th style="width: 15%;">Recipient Name</th>
                <th style="width: 15%;">Contact number</th>
                <th>Street name</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
                <th style="width: 150px;">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for address in addressInfo %}
            <tr class="row-address-book" style="text-align: center; text-wrap: stable; vertical-align: middle;">
                <td>
                    {% if address.15 == 1 %}
                    Default
                    <br>
                    {{address.3}}
                    {% else %}
                    {{address.3}}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.11}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.8}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.12}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button
                    class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-black"
                    type="button"
                    style="margin-bottom: 0px;"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button
                    class="btn-edit-address btn btn-sm mx-1"
                    type="button"
                    style="color: rgb(24, 115, 184); margin-bottom: 0px;"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <form action="{{ url_for('homepage.deleteBuyerAddress', addressBookID=address[0]) }}" class="form-delete-address" method="POST">
                        <button
                        class="btn-delete-address btn btn-sm mx-1"
                        type="submit"
                        style="color: red; margin-bottom: 0px;"
                        >
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

Here is my javascript:
$(".btn-delete-address").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            icon: "warning",
            title: "Delete address",
            text: "Do you wish to delete this address? You cannot recover this address once deleted.",
            type: "warning",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    text: "Delete",
                    className: "btn btn-success"
                },
                cancel: {
                    visible: true,
                    className: "btn btn-danger",
                },
            },
        }).then((deleteValue) => {
            if (deleteValue) {
                $(".form-delete-address").submit();
            };
        });
    });

Here is my python code for SQL query:
@homepage.route('/deleteBuyerAddress/<addressBookID>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def deleteBuyerAddress(addressBookID):
    if request.method=='POST':
        conn = get_db_connection()
        if conn is None:
            flash("NO DB CONNECTION", category='error')
            return redirect(url_for('homepage.home'))
        
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM address_book WHERE accountID=%s and addressBookID=%s", (session['accountID'], addressBookID))
            conn.commit()
            flash("Successfully deleted address!", category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('homepage.addressBook'))
        except Error as e:
            conn.rollback()
            flash(f"{e}", category='errpr')
            return redirect(url_for('homepage.addressBook'))
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()


I've already gone from using IDs to classes, but it still doesn't work. However, when I omit SweetAlert, like I just go straight to submitting the form and not even bother showing the pop-up, it works properly. What goes wrong?

$(".form-delete-address").submit(); - there's multiple .form-delete-address elements - you want only the one that's had its delete button clicked within

$(".btn-delete-address").click(function() { let delBtn = $(this); .... if (deleteValue) { delBtn.closest("form").submit(); } ...

it works properly now, thank you

You have created a form for deleting an address. Clicking the button will submit the form (I know you know that), but you listen for the click event on the button and that could get you in trouble. Instead listen for the submit event, and you can do that by listening for the event on the table (event delegation). Now, test if the form has the name "delete" (it is ok to have more forms with the same name) (and you could have other forms in your table that does other things).
When calling the deleteAddress() you know what specific form was submitted.


const table = document.getElementById('table-address-book');

table.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  switch (form.name) {
    case 'delete':
      deleteAddress(form);
      break;
  }
});

function deleteAddress(form) {
  swal({
    icon: "warning",
    title: "Delete address",
    text: "Do you wish to delete this address? You cannot recover this address once deleted.",
    type: "warning",
    buttons: {
      confirm: {
        text: "Delete",
        className: "btn btn-success"
      },
      cancel: {
        visible: true,
        className: "btn btn-danger",
      },
    },
  }).then((deleteValue) => {
    if (deleteValue) {
      form.submit();
    };
  });
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="table-responsive my-5">
  <table id="table-address-book" class="display table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th style="width: 15%;">Recipient Name</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;">Contact number</th>
        <th>Street name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for address in addressInfo %}
      <tr class="row-address-book" style="text-align: center; text-wrap: stable; vertical-align: middle;">
        <td>
          {% if address.15 == 1 %} Default
          <br> {{address.3}} {% else %} {{address.3}} {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.11}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.8}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p class="mx-1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{address.12}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-black" type="button" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
          <button class="btn-edit-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="button" style="color: rgb(24, 115, 184); margin-bottom: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
          <form name="delete" action="{{ url_for('homepage.deleteBuyerAddress', addressBookID=address[0]) }}" class="form-delete-address" method="POST">
            <button class="btn-delete-address btn btn-sm mx-1" type="submit" style="color: red; margin-bottom: 0px;">Delete<i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



